# Load the new tab window without the layout page details on SPA app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**app.js**

```
   $stateProvider.state('tenant.propertyGoogleMap', {
        url: '/PropertyGoogleMap',
        templateUrl: '~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/propertyGoogleMap.cshtml',
        menu: 'PropertyGoogleMap.Tenant'
    });
```

**JS**

Here I have loaded the new browser window tab when user clicks the button.

```
vm.propertyGoogleMap = function () {
                var url = $state.href('tenant.propertyGoogleMap', {}, { absolute: false });
                $window.open(url, '_blank');
            };
```

**propertyGoogleMap.cshtml**

```
<div ng-controller="tenant.views.propertymanagement.propertyGoogleMap as vm">

    <style type="text/css">
        .angular-google-map-container {
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>

   <div class="row">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center="vm.map.center" zoom="vm.map.zoom" options="vm.options"></ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my question is,could you tell me how can I load the new tab window without the layout page details ? I mean without menus and etc.. If I want, I can load angular and other related js files on that page (`propertyGoogleMap.cshtml`) manually.Thanks.

**Note :** The problem here is, when I use new window tab then it is being loaded whole application with the layout page and etc. If I can stop that then I think this should work.So how can I do that ?

I have tried with `@{Layout = null;}` also.But no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to remove it from the above mentioned page.So I have used CSS to do so :D

```
 .page-sidebar-wrapper, .page-header, .page-footer {
            display: none !important;
        }
```